# How to find the timezone with "HNEC" short name?

Tags: java, android, timezone

My Android app is using this code to get the short name of the timezone in which the handset is located.

```
String shortDisplayName = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

For my user in [Strasbourg, France](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=48.589598,7.739639&num=1&sll=48.57479,7.734375&sspn=22.132608,36.606445&ie=UTF8&ll=46.830134,6.328125&spn=22.866457,36.606445&z=5), `shortDisplayName` is "HNEC" (I haven't learned yet exactly which locale is in play).  I'm trying to determine exactly which TimeZone has that short name.  So, I threw together some quick test code:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for (String id : ids) {
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    int rawOffset = timeZone.getRawOffset();
    for (Locale locale : locales) {
        String shortDisplayName = timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT, locale);
        if (shortDisplayName.equalsIgnoreCase("HNEC")) {
            System.out.println(id + " | " + shortDisplayName + " | " + rawOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that code, no lines are printing.  That is, no timezones, using any locale, resolve to a shortname of "HNEC"?  How can I figure out which TimeZone has a short name of "HNEC"?

Comment: HNEC means "heure normale d'Europe centrale", french for "Central European Time : CET": http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heure_normale_d%27Europe_centrale .

Comment: Where are you getting "HNEC", lance?  I see ax's comment, and I understand what you want, but HNEC isn't a valid identifier for a timezone in the database Java uses.  Is this value coming from the third party system you mentioned in your other question?  Is it coming from the user directly, from his/her operating system?

Comment: The code redirects the user to a URL that takes timezone as a parameter.  I form that parameter's value using `shortDisplayName` from the first code snippet above.  He sent me the URL to which he's been redirected, and it shows "HNEC" as the timezone parameter's value.  Short of him sending me bad data, that value came from my code (running on a Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 that's running Android -- presumably 1.6, if that matters).  "Other question", for anyone who might be wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807197/get-three-letter-short-timezone-name-as-opposed-to-four-letter

Comment: http://icu-project.org/trac/ticket/5290 uses the "fr_FR" locale to print out "HNEC" for the "Europe/Paris" timezone.  Interesting.  So, do I need to use a different locale ("en_US", maybe) when calling getDisplayName()?

Comment: Good news: If you do that, you should get "CET" for Europe/Paris... which is kind of amusing, given the fact that the javadoc says the three-character version is deprecated.

Comment: Sooo.. what's going to happen if I get the short display name specifying the en_US locale..... if he doesn't have that locale installed on his Android device?  Will the "short name", at that point, become "GMT+01:00"?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that.  This question has passed over the limits of my knowledge: I have never worked on the Android platform.