# Three-letter time zone IDs inconsistent in Android

Tags: java, android, date, timezone

I am using the basic Java format of zzz in Android to get the timezone appended. Please find the code below

```
public static final String DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz";    
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    DISPLAY_DATE_FORMAT);
formatter.setTimeZone(timeZone);
date = formatter.format(formattedDateTime);
```

So the result I am getting in both the platfrom is

> In version 6.0.1 it is showing GMT-04:00 and in 5.1.1 as EST which is kind of odd.

I also tried using the following code

```
timeZone.getDisplayName(timeZone.inDaylightTime(formattedDateTime),TimeZone.SHORT);
```

and got the same result. Is there any way, I can get the EST instead of GMT appended values. 
I know this method is depricated as per oracle, but is there any way I can still get the Three letter timezoneID.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807197/get-three-letter-short-timezone-name-as-opposed-to-four-letter

Answer (score 0):

The 3-4 letter abbreviations as commonly seen in the mainstream media are not true time zones. They are not standardized. They are not even unique!

Modern date-time libraries eschew these abbreviations, instead using proper time zone names.

See [this list of proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). They are in a format of `continent/region`. For example, `America/Montreal` and `Asia/Kolkata`.

> 2016-06-11T12:34.56-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

You are using old date-time classes that are notoriously troublesome and poorly designed. They have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 (ThreeTen-Backport) and further adapted to Android ([ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).