# In Android 8.0 are the three-letter time zone IDs supported?

Tags: android

Instead of GMT+/-offset, are some android devices returning 3 letter IDs instead when looking at time zones?

Comment: Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807197/get-three-letter-short-timezone-name-as-opposed-to-four-letter

Comment: How about if I always want them in GMT+/-offset format?